# Lottie animation is hiding layers in android. (React Native)

Tags: react-native, lottie

I am running into an issue where exported json files are working fine in-browser and on iOS, but are breaking on Android. Specifically, certain elements are not rendering properly on android and are simply not appearing.

I would expect that the animation would play on both iOS and Android, but  The animation plays correctly on iOS, but on Android key elements are hidden or missing.

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

iOS:
[image: iOS]

Android: 
[image: Android]

Comment: So a lot of the effects in the bodymovin plugin do support both ios and android but it doesnt do a great job of highlighting the ones that dont. Fortunately the airbnb documentation website gives you a sort of cheat sheet for all things that work and dont work on the different platforms. http://airbnb.io/lottie/supported-features.html

Comment: Nemi Shah, I don't think that I am using any after effects setting that should work on iOS but not the others. The only effect I see that only works on iOS is Intersect Masks, but I'm not using those at all. Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: Well like I said it's not a full proof cheat sheet and sometimes they don't document everything or miss something out, also I know for a fact certain type of strokes and colors don't work as fully cross platform( faced this at work) try one of the jsons from the Lottie community showcase and see if they work fine in both. If they do then it's something to do with your json and you might have to do your animations in parts to see which one is actually the problem. If the community showcase doesn't work the same on both then it could be something with the library. Wish I could give you more info

Comment: Thanks for the help troubleshooting. I ended up using the lottie app to find that my export process from illustrator included merge paths on some layers even though I didn't need the functionality at all. I was able to delete them in AE without any effect on the animation whatsoever, and it looks like it is working on all devices now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the lottie app to find that my export process from illustrator included merge paths on some layers even though I didn't need the functionality at all. I was able to delete them in AE without any effect on the animation whatsoever, and it looks like it is working on all devices now.

Thanks to Nemi Shah (above) for the help